# Laravel 5.2 - How to echo a field from a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model

Im trying to echo the categoryid field from the with('categorys').

My appserviceprovider:

```
view()->composer('welcome' , function($view){
       $view->with('homerings', Ring::where('homepage', '=', 1)->with('categorys')->get()->all());
    });
```

Where i'm trying to echo it in welcome.blade.php.

```
@foreach($homerings as $ring)
            {{ dd($ring->categorys) }}
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="img-responsive homepage-ring" src="{{url($ring->image)}}" alt="{{$ring->title}}">
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
                $i++;
            ?>
            @if($i == 4)
                </div>
                <div class="row">
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

[image]

Normal i think it should work like:

```
{{ dd($ring->categorys->categoryid) }}
```

But this is not working.
the error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$categoryid (View: /resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error tells you "Undefined property ...Collection::$categoryid". It means you are trying to access the `categoryid` property of a `Collection` object instead of a `Category` object.

When you defined a relationship where many can be returned (like `hasMany()`), Eloquent will return a `Collection` (more than one) of results. When you define an one-to-one relation, eloquent will return only one result and therefore the Model it is related to.

To retrieve the first model in you collection you could do something like:

```
$category = $ring->categorys()->first(); // Get first 

echo $category->categoryid;
```

However since your relation will return many I think you would like to have something like:

```
$categories = $ring->categorys; // Get all categories

@foreach ($categories as $category) // Loop

    {{ $category->categoryid }} // Echo categoryid

@endforeach
```

Hope this helps :)

Ps: the plural form of category is categories

Comment: This helped. Thank you Thomas.